# Setting an image from a file in Today Widget

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8-today-widget

I'm having a strange issue where I cannot set a button image (or a UIImageView.image) programmatically. I can set the image in the storyboard, but if I try to change it, the app freezes up. Example. I have copied the image into the folder and can use that image to set the button in storyboard.

```
[self.picButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Are you sure the `picButton` `IBOutlet` is linked? Are you sure the image name is correct?

Comment: Yes, I can for example change the color of the title text programmatically. This works:     [self.picButton setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

I've copied the image name multiple times and even renamed it and brought in other images

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add widget target for the images or other assets you want to use in the widget.